# Finding a change of variables to give a homogeneous linear system.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in the process of completing an assignment and have come across a question that's stumped me. If anyone could give a pointer on where to begin I'd very much appreciate it.
Anyway, here's the question:

Given $A = \begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\3&-5\end{bmatrix}$, $b = \begin{bmatrix}0\\6\end{bmatrix}$ and $\textbf{Y} =\begin{bmatrix}y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

let $\textbf{Y′} = A \textbf{Y} + b$

Now, find the change in variables 
$$
p = y - a
$$
$$
q = z - b
$$

for some real a, b so that gives the homogeneous
linear system $\textbf{X′} = B \textbf{X}$ where $\textbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}$

I'd really appreciate the help. The 'change in variables' part especially trips me up.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\mathbf Y ' &= \begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\3&-5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y\\z\end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}0\\6\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\3&-5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p+a\\q+b\end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}0\\6\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2(p+a) - 4(q+b)\\3(p+a)-5(q+b)+6\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\begin{bmatrix}2p-4q\\3p-5q\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}2a - 4b\\3a -
 5b + 6\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

In order to make this system linear in $p$ and $q$, the new coordinates, we want to set $a$ and $b$ to eliminate the $+const$ component. That way we can express $\mathbf Y '$ as follows:

$$\mathbf Y' = \begin{bmatrix}2&-4\\3&-5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}$$
...which is linear rather than affine.

So we solve for:

$$\begin{cases}0 = 2a-4b \\
0 = 3a - 5b + 6\end{cases}$$

From which it follows that $a=2b$ and $b+6=0$.

The solution is then $a=-12, b=-6$ so that $p = y + 12$ and $q = z + 6$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I understand what is actually going on now.

Comment: Just as a followup question, what would the matrix B become? Would it stay the same as matrix A?

Comment: You haven't defined $\mathbf X'$ so I can't say.

Comment: $\textbf{Y'}=\begin{bmatrix}y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}$ is this what you mean?

Comment: Okay well in that case, $\mathbf X' = \mathbf Y'$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.